# How to change active admin filters with ransack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I've got 3 models:

```
Product
  id
  name
  price
  ...
```

```
Order
  id
  user_id
  priority
```

```
Ordered_product
  id
  order_id
  product_id
  ...
```

In Active Admin - (`Orders page`), I need to create filter which will show orders with appropriate product (from select).

I can't find any good example how to create something similar with ransack, and without it it doesn’t work.
So, may someone help me, and say how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Kaama, If I understood correctly, you want to show the number of the order along with all products?

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup the associations between your models?

```
# in you Order model:
has_many :ordered_products
has_many :products, :through => :ordered_products

# then in your ActiveAdmin register block:
filter :products
```

Should work.